# When implementing a Clojure protocol, can an overloaded method call its overloaded counterpart?

Tags: clojure

Here's part of an overloaded protocol definition:

```
(defprotocol ClientProtocol
  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV] 
    [this outV label inV data])
```

And here's part of its implementation:

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.client
  (:use [bulbs.base.client :only [ClientProtocol]]))

(deftype Neo4jClient [ns config]
  ClientProtocol

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV data]
    (let [inV-uri (utils/normalize-uri (build-path neo4j-uri vertex-path inV))
          path (build-path vertex-path, outV, "relationships")
          params {:to inV-uri, :type label, :data (first data)}]
      (post config path params)))

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV]
    ;; it doesn't like this call...
    (create-edge this outV label inV nil))
```

It's spewing this error when the second method tries to call the first:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: create-edge in this context
```

I had both definitions working earlier in SLIME when I compiled it with the first function and then went back and added the second.

But when I moved the protocol definition into a separate file and tried to re-compile the whole thing, it throws an error when the second method tries to call the first, presumably because the first method hasn't been defined yet.

The Clojure `reify` docs have this comment:

> If a method is overloaded in a protocol/interface, multiple
>   independent method definitions must be supplied.

http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reify

I suppose these are not *independent* definitions.

What's the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace declaration is wrong.

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.client
  (:use [bulbs.base.client :only [ClientProtocol]]))
```

Protocol functions are normal Clojure functions and have to treated as such. So you have to include them in your `:only` clause.

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.client
  (:use [bulbs.base.client :only [create-edge ClientProtocol]]))
```

Comment: Thanks -- since there are many functions in the protocol and a one-to-one mapping from the protocol definition file to the client implementation, I just dropped the `:only` bit altogether and now use `(:use [bulbs.base.client])`. My initial confusion was from not realizing how protocols work -- not realizing that the protocol is where the namespace definition comes from, not the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stipped down example that works in clojure 1.4.0

```
(ns hello.core)
(defprotocol ClientProtocol
 (create-edge
    [this outV label inV] 
    [this outV label inV data]))

(deftype Neo4jClient []
  ClientProtocol

 (create-edge
   [this outV label inV data]
    4)

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV]
    (create-edge this outV label inV nil)))

hello.core> (create-edge (Neo4jClient.) 2 3 4)
4

hello.core> (create-edge (Neo4jClient.) 2 3 4 5)
4
```

---

and here is a mutually recursive example (no base case)

```
(deftype Neo4jClient []
  ClientProtocol

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV data]
    (println "OMG im in a looooooop...")
    (create-edge this 1 2 3))

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV]
    (println "AHHH im in a looooooop...")
    (create-edge this 1 2 3 4)))


hello.core> (create-edge (Neo4jClient.) 1 2 3 4)
OMG im in a looooooop...
AHHH im in a looooooop...
OMG im in a looooooop...
AHHH im in a looooooop...
OMG im in a looooooop...
AHHH im in a looooooop...
OMG im in a looooooop...
AHHH im in a looooooop...
```

Comment: Where do you see mutual recursion in my example? It looks like the problem occurs when you import the protocol definition -- you have to supply the namespace to function its calling.

Comment: @espeed - Yes, you are correct, if the protocol is defined in a different

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here works fine.

Consider this example:

```
(defprotocol ClientProtocol
  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV]
    [this outV label inV data]))

(deftype SampleClient []
  ClientProtocol

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV]
      (create-edge this outV label inV {}))

  (create-edge
    [this outV label inV data]
      {:action :create-edge :this this :outV outV :label label :inV inV :data data}))
```

Behavior when run is as-expected:

```
; => (create-edge (SampleClient.) 1 2 3)
{:action :create-edge, :this #<SampleClient user.SampleClient@63a2cc03>,
 :outV 1, :label 2, :inV 3, :data {}}
; => (create-edge (SampleClient.) 1 2 3 4)
{:action :create-edge, :this #<SampleClient user.SampleClient@7144c1a4>,
 :outV 1, :label 2, :inV 3, :data 4}
```